# MVC: Cannot delete a row from the grid using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I understand it is good practice to delete a row in a grid using AJAX.
So I found this reference as to how to do it here;

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/simple-jquery-delete-link-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx

However when I try to created a html helper, I find that the RouteLink property has a red line underneath it - intellisense says it doesn't exist.
What am I doing wrong?

```
        public static string DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText
  , Leave employeeOtherLeave)
        {
            return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Payroll",
                new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = employeeOtherLeave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
                new { onclick = "$.post(this.href); return false;" });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460117.aspx) extension method is defined in a class belonging to the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace. So you need to add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` at the top of your file.

Comment: You have correctly answered the question and I will tick you for that. However I get the red line in my View for <%: Html.DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave("Delete", Model.LeaveId)%>. Why is that?

Comment: @arame3333, because in your view you also need to include the namespace in which this custom helper is defined: `<%@ Import Namespace="Namespace.Where.Your.Extension.Method.Is.Defined" %>` or simply add it to the `namespaces` section of your `web.config`.